# TypeError: undefined is not an object when unit testing with jasmine - JSON response

Tags: javascript, json, karma-jasmine

I added this line in an existing unit test which used to work and I'm getting an error after adding this:(BTW, this works ok on web browser.)

```
onRender: function () {
    if ( _.isEmpty(this.viewData.assessment) || _.isEmpty(this.viewData.patient) || _.isEmpty(this.viewData.scoreInfo) ) {
      $("#viewAssessmentDetails").hide();
      return;
    }
    //console.log("this.viewData.scoreInfo: ",JSON.stringify(this.viewData.scoreInfo));
    if (this.completedAssessment) {
      this.viewData.assessment = this.completedAssessment.toJSON();
    }
    
   //without this line, the test passes
   this.viewData.assessment.format.sections[0].questions[0].introText =
      this.viewData.assessment.format.sections[0].questions[0].introText.replace(/\|/g, '\n');
...
...
```

the error I get:

FAILED TESTS:

```
viewAssessmentDetails
    ✖ render no completed assessment renders
      PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Mac OS 0.0.0)
    TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.viewData.assessment.format.sections') in src/test/view/app/view_assessment_detailsSpec.js (line 49131)
    onRender@webpack:///src/js/view/app/view_assessment_details.js:368:5 <- src/test/view/app/view_assessment_detailsSpec.js:49131:72948
    webpack:///src/test/view/app/view_assessment_detailsSpec.js:253:9 <- src/test/view/app/view_assessment_detailsSpec.js:50821:88
    <Jasmine>

    ✖ render with completed assessment renders
      PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Mac OS 0.0.0)
    TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.viewData.assessment.format') in src/test/view/app/view_assessment_detailsSpec.js (line 49131)
    onRender@webpack:///src/js/view/app/view_assessment_details.js:368:5 <- src/test/view/app/view_assessment_detailsSpec.js:49131:72941
    webpack:///src/test/view/app/view_assessment_detailsSpec.js:265:9 <- src/test/view/app/view_assessment_detailsSpec.js:50840:88
    <Jasmine>
```

thanks in advance,
Daniel